# Can you share Docker Images uploaded to Google Container Registry between different accounts?

Tags: kubernetes, google-container-registry

We'd like to have a separate test and prod project on the Google Cloud Platform but we want to reuse the same docker images in both environments. Is it possible for the Kubernetes cluster running on the test project to use images pushed to the prod project? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your question, I believe by account you mean project.

The [command](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/#pulling_from_the_registry) for pulling an image from the registry  is:

```
$ gcloud docker pull gcr.io/your-project-id/example-image
```

This means as long as your account is a member of the project which the image belongs to, you can pull the image from that project to any other projects that your account is a member of.

Comment: You're right about account, sorry for the confusion. But how can I give a Kubernetes cluster access to the GCR of another project?

Comment: Push the image to your prod project. This way, you can continue your testing without introducing testing mistakes to the prod project. Although you can create your pods on prod project using the images directly from test project:  `$ kubectl run pod-name --image=gcr.io/your-test-project-id/example-image`

Comment: In order for this solution to work I added to compute engine default service account of the project that needed access to the project with the docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible since the container [images](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/images.html) are on a per-container basis.